# What are the criteria for the existence of Top Answerers section?

Tags: support, tags

For some tags, there is a Top Answerers section that shows the top five. For other tags, there aren't.

What are the criteria for the existence of this section?

Comment: The section is always there, provided you are on the tag info page for a tag and there *are* top answerers. Where did you expect to see the side-bare section but don't find one?

Comment: I think I happened to hit a rarely used tag. As long as there is a single answer (to a single question), there is this section for that tag?

Comment: yes; not all tags *have* answers with upvotes, but even then the header is there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Top Answerers section *always* is shown, on the tag info page.

If there are fewer than 5 top answerers, that actual list of names can be shorter, even to the point of having no answerers to list, but in that case the *header* is still shown:

> [image: empty top answerers list]